# How to pull commerce_customer_address into the invoices view?

Tags: views, commerce

I'm using Drupal Commerce for a hotel booking site so it's not following the typical Commerce use case. It works very well except for an issue I'm having where the Billing Info is not being automatically populated with the Account Info. This works in Commerce but not the way I'm using it. I spoke to some Commerce peeps and they confirmed this. As a work around and since I'm not using the Billing Info fields anyways, I thought why not just use the Account Info fields?

Well the problem is that I can't seem to call on commerce_customer_address in the invoices view. I don't see it in the relationships section. Does anyone know how I can do this? As a proof of concept, I added an entity reference field to orders and was able to manually pull the address from Account Info. I'd like to automatically pull this info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your situation properly, it sounds like you want to establish a relationship from an order to the user account that created it and include a field from the user account in the Views results. If so, the solution is the core Drupal Commerce relationship *Commerce Order: Owner*. With this relationship, you should be able to put any property or field of the user account responsible for the order into your Views results.

This relationship is a part of the admin Orders View by default, so perhaps there's something else going on in your case. If so, it would be helpful to know more about your customizations.

Comment: Thank you. It seems as though I need to revisit the documentation on Relationships. The module I was using had a bug fix that took care of this obstacle.